# How do I add the bibliography file (.bib) in my .docx when converting from .tex to .docx?

Tags: pandoc, convert

I need to convert a `.tex` file to `.docx` and I am trying to use `pandoc` for the first time. I manage to convert but the bibliography is missing and the citations do not appear. The tex file contains an external bibliography `reference.bib` located in the same folder of the file I want to convert.

I have tried the commands below to convert, but none of them worked:

```
pandoc -s JEEQ-D-21-00161R1.tex -o JEEQ-D-21-00161R1.docx --bibliography=reference.bib

pandoc -s JEEQ-D-21-00161R1.tex -o JEEQ-D-21-00161R1.docx --bibliography=/Users/maykelboldrinbelluzi/Documents/pandoc-test/reference.bibtex

pandoc --bibliography reference.bib --filter pandoc-citeproc -o JEEQ-D-21-00161R1.docx JEEQ-D-21-00161R1.tex
```

I don't know if or how to install the package `pandoc-citeproc`. I type in the cmd terminal and everytime I type the command with `pandoc-citeproc` it returns a message

> [WARNING] Deprecated: pandoc-citeproc filter. Use --citeproc instead.
> Error running filter pandoc-citeproc: Could not find executable
> pandoc-citeproc

Do you guys have an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 4):

Add the `--citeproc` option (ps: next time provide a minimal working example):

```
pandoc --bibliography=myrefs.bib --citeproc -o output.docx input.tex
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@Book{Knuth:1990,
    author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
    title     = {The {\TeX}book},
    year      = {1990},
    isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}

@Book{Lamport:94,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Main Body}
{\LaTeX} is aTuring-complete (procedural) markup language and typesetting processor~\cite{Lamport:94}.

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{myrefs}
\end{document}
```